# $ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{z\in\Bbb C:z^n=1\}=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Is $$ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{z\in\Bbb C:z^n=1\}=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}$$my argument is that the argument of the elements of the first set are rational multiples of $\pi$ whereas the second set also consists of elements with irrational multiples of $\pi$.
But I am not so sure, there is still some doubt.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those two sets are certainly not equal.

$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{z\,|\,z^n=1,n\in \mathbb N\}$ is countable as it is a countable union of finite sets, while $\{z/|z|=1\}$ has the [cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum).

Comment: What does "power of a continuum" mean?

Comment: I edited as *power of the continuum* is a too fast translation from French! I mean the *cardinality of the continuum*, i.e. has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.

Comment: "power of the continuum" is also a common term for it in English, but is perhaps becoming antiquated (as am I).

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'm afraid of becoming antiquated too. Let's reassure ourselves in saying that we're like the good Armagnac's (or Cognac's depending on your taste).

Comment: This is correct, but feels like a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Maybe why it's obvious the LHS contains only rational powers of $i$ would be easier to follow.

Comment: @drjpizzle I don't really agree. Perhaps (probably) my perspective is warped from doing too much math, but the cardinality difference is what my mind *immediately* went to, at which point the answer is obviously "no". The benefit is that it gives an answer at an appropriate level of abstraction revealing what details are important and which are not. Not having to worry about unimportant details simplifies things. In this case, I don't need to know what the solutions of $z^n=1$ look like, only that there are finitely many of them. Dubs' solution requires knowing what those solutions look like.

Answer (score 12):

Your argument is correct.

For example, $e^{\sqrt{2} \pi i}$ is not in the first set.